# Hamburger menu works but after I click on menu link it disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I am having is with my Hamburger menu. I have a one page site in place so the links in the navigation go to a certain section in the page.  When I click on the hamburger menu it opens my navigation and when I click on any of the links the navigation goes to the correct spot and closes which I want but the hamburger menu disappears all together.  How do I get the menu to disappear on link click but have the hamburger menu go back to how it was and be available to click again?  This is for my personal portfolio project and I am still new to jquery.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="menu-section">
<div class="menu-toggle">
<div class="one"></div>
 <div class="two"></div>
 <div class="three"></div>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.menu-toggle.on .one {
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
}


.menu-toggle.on .two {
  opacity: 0;
}



.menu-toggle.on .three {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
}


.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: @color2;
  margin: 6px auto;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
 }




nav ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}



nav ul a {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: @color2;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu' sans-serif;

}




nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: @color4;
}



.menu-section.on {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.menu-section').toggleClass('on');
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('hidden');

     e.preventDefault();
   });


  $('nav ul a').click(function () {
    $('.menu-section').hide();

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually jQuery's `.hide()` method sets the display of the target element to none.

```
$('nav ul a').click(function () {
  $('.menu-section').hide();
});
```

what you need to do instead is to toggle the "on" class on the `.menu-section` element and also toggle everything else back to the initial state:

```
$('nav ul a').click(function () {
  $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('on');
  $('.menu-section').toggleClass('on');
  $('nav ul').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Ahh,  that makes sense,  works like a charm!  Thank you!